# Modify dataframe values with mutate in R

Tags: r, case, mutate

[image]I have a dataset that has only one variable v.

I want to calculate for every new row the previous cumulative max value of v (maxprix) and the previous cumulative standard deviation (sdd).

For every row I want to test if the v is bigger than maxprix + 2.5 sdd.
If it is the case, v become maxprix + sdd. And next maxprix and sdd take the modification of v into account

But case_when(), modify only the first occurence that satisfy the condition.

How can I modify all values( raw5, 8 and 10)

```
library(dplyr)
```

v<-c(1,2,3,4,50,6,7,1000,9,1200,10)
data = data.frame(v)
data

#after modification

data<-data%>%
mutate(maxprix= ave(v, FUN=function(x) sapply(sapply(seq_along(x)-1, head, x=x), max)))%>%
mutate(sdd=ave(v,FUN=function(x) sapply(sapply(seq_along(x)-1, head, x=x), sd)))%>%
mutate(v= case_when(v>maxprix+(2.5 * sdd) ~ (maxprix + sdd),
TRUE ~ (v)))%>%
mutate(maxprix= ave(v, FUN=function(x) sapply(sapply(seq_along(x)-1, head, x=x), max)))%>%
mutate(sdd= ave(v,FUN=function(x) sapply(sapply(seq_along(x)-1, head, x=x), sd)))

data

Comment: Might help if you provide a table with the expected output.

Comment: I added an output of my execution